# I can't figure out how to use Promise correctly in this context

Tags: node.js

`webhookClient.send(temp);`
executed earlier than
`temp['files'] = [link];`
`contains++;`
I need to wait for this.
`tg_bot.getFileLink` - promise
How to sync it correctly?

```
 let contains = 0
let temp = {
    username: `${msg.from.first_name} tg`,
};
const user_profile = tg_bot.getUserProfilePhotos(msg.from.id);
user_profile
    .then(function (res) {
        tg_bot.getFileLink(res.photos[0][0].file_id)
            .then(link => { temp['avatarURL'] = link;})
            .then( () => {
                if (msg.text !== undefined) {
                    temp['content'] = msg.text;
                    contains++;}})
            .then(() => {
                if (msg.photo !== undefined) {
                    let link = tg_bot.getFileLink(msg.photo.slice(-1)[0].file_id)
                        .then(link =>{
                                temp['files'] = [link];
                                contains++;})}})
            .then(() => {
                    if (contains <= 0) temp['content'] = 'empty';
                    console.log(temp);
                    webhookClient.send(temp);})

});
```

Comment: the logical solution is to just move .then...webhookClient.send... after g_bot.getFileLink but i plan to do a lot of checks, it doesn't fit, there will be callback hell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code really lends itself to using `await` so you don't have to deal with nested `.then()` handlers and it's much easier to deal with branching in your code flow.  This is a classic example of why `await` was invented (to make code like this simpler to write and debug).

This assumes it is inside an `async` tagged function:

```
let contains = 0
let temp = {
    username: `${msg.from.first_name} tg`,
};

const res = await tg_bot.getUserProfilePhotos(msg.from.id);
temp['avatarURL'] = await tg_bot.getFileLink(res.photos[0][0].file_id);
if (msg.text !== undefined) {
    temp['content'] = msg.text;
    contains++;
}
if (msg.photo !== undefined) {
    let link = await tg_bot.getFileLink(msg.photo.slice(-1)[0].file_id);
    temp['files'] = [link];
    contains++;
}
if (contains <= 0) {
    temp['content'] = 'empty';
}
webhookClient.send(temp);
```

---

If you wanted to make this work without `await`, using only `.then()`, then you just have to chain the conditional call to `getFileLink()` (by returning its promise) so that the next `.then()` block will wait for it:

```
let contains = 0;
let temp = {
    username: `${msg.from.first_name} tg`,
};
const user_profile = tg_bot.getUserProfilePhotos(msg.from.id);
user_profile.then(function(res) {
    return tg_bot.getFileLink(res.photos[0][0].file_id).then(link => {
        temp['avatarURL'] = link;
    }).then(() => {
        if (msg.text !== undefined) {
            temp['content'] = msg.text;
            contains++;
        }
        if (msg.photo !== undefined) {
            return tg_bot.getFileLink(msg.photo.slice(-1)[0].file_id).then(link => {
                temp['files'] = [link];
                contains++;
            });
        }
    }).then(() => {
        if (contains <= 0) {
            temp['content'] = 'empty';
        }
        console.log(temp);
        webhookClient.send(temp);
    });
});
```

Note how I've also flattened the nesting and combined `.then()` blocks that didn't have to be separate.

---

Note: both these implementations needs error handling.  The first needs a `try/catch` around it to catch any rejections from any of the `await` statements (or the caller needs to catch the rejected promise the `async` function would return.

The second implementation needs a `.catch()` at the end of the chain.